# Alternatives to ctags: are rtags, uctags or other alternatives better?

Tags: tags, ctags, filetype-c++

The problem: I've used ctags with C++ code for a while, but that has no knowledge of the code. If there are many subclasses that overwrite a certain virtual function, then on a Ctrl-] I may end up in the definition of an unexpected subclass.

Are there better ways to do this?
I've seen recommendation for rtags and uctags, are these viable and better alternatives as of now? Why?

Answer (score 2):

[On SO, I've written recently about uctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652773/should-i-use-universal-ctags):

> Regarding C++, it makes the difference -- I can't tell regarding C or
>   Java. It has a better understanding of C++ code bases than exuberant
>   ctags.
>
> Otherwise, it's maintained, with unit tests. If it was a fork of an
>   active project, well I may not be able to sort the two. In this case,
>   it's a fork of an unmaintained project. It's built upon what ex-ctags
>   had to offer to offer, let's hope, more.

It's likely to be even better with rtags as it's based on clang. But also, I expect it to be slower than uctags, and likely more tricky to set up correctly as all other clang based plugins are.